# Fedora: Run pascal program in geany

Tags: terminal, installation, fedora, pascal, geany

I am trying to learn programming pascal and want to use geany as IDE.

I created a simple hello world example, which I can compile. But when trying to run the program using F5 I get an error saying:

"Could not find terminal program "/bin/sh %c"

Does anyone know how I have to set up geany to run my program?

Comment: So say something constructive: the error seems to indicate that geany doesn't know the name of the generated program file (the name of the main program).

Comment: Just found the reason why it did not work. Had to select a proper path to terminal in 'Properties' -> 'Tool'.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you should just install fpc (free pascal compiler)!

maybe sth like this!

```
sudo apt-get install fp-compiler-2.6.2
```